# C - Color characters in console window (Linux)

Tags: c, linux, colors, character

I'm building a server and client (chatroom) in Linux, and I want to colorize one word (the username) in the character buffer that echoes in the client. Here how the buffer is echoed when a user enters the chat:

```
        strncpy(clients[clientIndex].username, buf, BUF_SIZE); // copy buffer to username
        bzero(buf, BUF_SIZE); // zero out buffer

        strncpy(buf, "User added to chat.", BUF_SIZE); // new user added
        strncpy(buf, "Welcome, ", 9); // add welcome message to buffer

        // concatenate so that the buffer reads "Welcome, [username]"
        strncat(buf, clients[clientIndex].username, BUF_SIZE - 9);
```

The only method I know of coloring text is:

```
#define KMAG  "\x1B[35m"
.
.
.
printf(KMAG "Welcome\n");
```

<strike>But obviously I am not using printf()</strike> since the server and client must send and receive these messages. I need a way to color only one word in the buffer. I imagine something that might look like this:

```
strcpy(clients[clientIndex].username, KMAG);
```

Where I can assign a color to characters themselves, and not just change the way it is printed.
Does such a method of coloring text exist?

---

EDIT: my mistake. I am using printf... just very unsure how to implement a color on certain characters in the buffer I am printing

This is how the code is printed in client:

```
void recvMessageFromServer() {
    while (1) {
        /* print the server's reply */
        n = recvfrom(sockfd, buf, BUFSIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &serveraddr,
                &serverlen);
        if (n < 0)
            error("ERROR in recvfrom");


        printf("%s\n", buf);
    }
}
```

Comment: *But obviously I am not using `printf()`* - So what are you using to print in the console (client)?

Comment: My mistake, I updated my question to include how I am handling received messages.

Comment: Who is deciding on the color? The sending client? The server? The receiving client?

Comment: Me. I want to (hardcode) colorize a client's username myself. This way I can get an understanding of how I can do more with it.

Comment: @EugeneSh. thank you for quick replies

Comment: Why is the server responsible for presentation?

Comment: There is no *you* in this project. There is server and multiple clients. If client knows how to distinguish the part you want to colorize, let it do it. (Your `buf` might have some fixed structure where the username is separated by, say, colon, so you can easily parse it out, print colored and then print the rest.)

Comment: Good explanation, thank you. So the client may select the color from a something like a color table. And I can just split and parse it upon printing, depending on what the client selected.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams the client is responsible for presentation. The server echoes back the response if the message was passed successfully

Answer (score 0):

the server 'could' set the colors by:

```
strcat( buf, '%s", "\x1B[35m" ); 
strncat( buf, "clients[clientIndex].username, 9); 
strcat( buf, "%s", "\x1b[30m" );
```

which will set the 'username' (limited to 9 characters) text to magneta, then set any following text to black